# Players not showing up on live Game Center Leaderboard

Tags: ios, iphone, game-center

I have recently released my app to the store and not all players are showing up on the leaderboard in the game centre app. When I look at the leaderboard scores there is half the number of scores that should be there. When I go to iTunesConnect > My App > Game Centre > Manage Scores and Players > Manage I see the correct number of scores. Why don't all these scores show up on the leaderboard?

Comment: I reckon it's a bug in the code.

Comment: The leaderboard I am referring to is the game centre leaderboard... in the game centre app. Do you mean it is a bug in apple? The scores are showing up in the manage section correctly... I figure that means I am reporting the scores correctly. 
I updated the question to say the leaderboard is in the GC app.